# Why this jsfiddle does not work for Kendo Knockout Sortable widget?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, kendo-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

```
<ul class="ones" data-bind="foreach: itemsOne, kendoSortable: { data: itemsOne, connectWith: '.twos' }">
    <li class="item" data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>

<hr/><div data-bind="foreach: itemsOne"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>,</div><hr/>

<ul class="twos" data-bind="foreach: itemsTwo, kendoSortable: { data: itemsTwo, connectWith: '.ones' }">
    <li class="item" data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>

<hr/><div data-bind="foreach: itemsTwo"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>,</div>

var ViewModel = function() {
    this.itemsOne = ko.observableArray([
        { name: "one" },
        { name: "two" },
        { name: "three" }
    ]);

    this.itemsTwo = ko.observableArray([
        { name: "four" },
        { name: "five" },
        { name: "six" }
    ]);
};
```

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

The fiddle is:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdudeja/X7y2k/

I have included all js files. Just the class named 'ones' and 'twos' is not there. This example is straight from the documentation url:

http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Sortable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Knockout-Kendo needs to be included after the Knockout and Kendo scripts have loaded.

```
   http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/js/knockout-kendo.min.js
```

This one needs to be moved to the end.  Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/zzYjX/

Comment: I have this same fiddle in my code now and when I played around with it, after 2-3 complete shift of items from one list to another, the UI becomes garbled. Sometimes, only one item remains in total, sometimes complete UI disappears. This is occurring in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pdudeja/mZ6hg/ as well as this current fiddle you have posted.

Comment: Does not seem to happen with just kendoSortable itself (no KO binding). Will have to dig into what values are being supplied to the event handlers.